# Appending data to list

Tags: android, list, android-listview

I am displaying data from two different API calls inside suggestion list so I'm calling two API's inside onQueryTextChange() .Since I am getting response from two different api calls i am using addAll() to append response from different apis.But data is not added and size of list is zero.But if i use `searchResponses= (List<UserVideo>) response;` then data is added to list but two different responses is not appended.Where am i going wrong?

```
     @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s)
        {

                if(s.length()>=1) {
                String mStart = "";
              int mCount = 10;

                    String[] columnNames = {"_id", "name", "userImage", "location"};
                    final String[] temp = new String[4];
                    final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);

  SearchAPI.getSearchFeed(getApplicationContext(), s, mStart, mCount, mSettingsManager.getInstance().getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Object response) {


                        searchResponses.addAll((List<UserVideo>) response);


                        for (UserVideo searchResponse :searchResponses)
                        {searchResponse.setIsVideo(true);
                            temp[0] = Long.toString(id++);
                            temp[1] = searchResponse.getCaption();

                            temp[3] = searchResponse.getLocation();

                            cursor.addRow(temp);
                        }

                        mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, cursor));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VolleyError error) {

                        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                        }

                    }
                });
              SearchAPI.getSearchUser(getApplicationContext(), s,mSettingsManager.getInstance().getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Object response)
                    {

                        searchResponses.addAll((List<UserVideo>) response);

                        for (UserVideo searchResponse :searchResponses) {
                            searchResponse.setIsVideo(false);
                            temp[0] = Long.toString(id++);
                            temp[1] = searchResponse.getUserName2();

                            temp[3] = searchResponse.getName();

                            cursor.addRow(temp);
                        }
                    mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, cursor));


                }
     @Override
                public void onError(VolleyError error)
                {

                    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                    }


                }
            });
        }

    return true;
    }
```

Updated according to DavidJohns answer-

```
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s)
    {

           if(s.length()>=0) {
            String mStart = "";
          int mCount = 10;

                String[] columnNames = {"_id", "name", "userImage", "location"};
                final String[] temp = new String[4];
                final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
               SearchAPI.getSearchFeed(getApplicationContext(), s, mStart, mCount, mSettingsManager.getInstance().getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Object response) {


                 searchResponses= (List<UserVideo>) response;


                        for (UserVideo searchResponse :searchResponses)
                        {
                            searchResponse.setIsVideo(true);
                            temp[0] = Long.toString(id++);
                            temp[1] = searchResponse.getCaption();
                               temp[2] =  searchResponse.getUserId();
                            temp[3] = searchResponse.getLocation();


                            cursor.addRow(temp);
                        }

                        mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, cursor));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VolleyError error) {

                        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                        }

                    }
                });
              SearchAPI.getSearchUser(getApplicationContext(), s,mSettingsManager.getInstance().getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Object response)
                    {
                        searchUserResponses= (List<UserVideo>) response;


                        for (UserVideo searchResponse :searchUserResponses) {
                            searchResponse.setIsVideo(false);
                            temp[0] = Long.toString(id++);
                            temp[1] = searchResponse.getUserName2();
                            temp[2] =  searchResponse.getUserId();
                            temp[3] = searchResponse.getName();
                            searchResponses.add(searchResponse);
                            cursor.addRow(temp);
                        }


                        mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, cursor));


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VolleyError error)
                    {

                        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                        }


                    }
                });
            }

        return true;
    }
 @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int i)
    {



       if((searchResponses!=null)&&(searchResponses.get(i).getIsVideo()))
       {

                UserVideo searchResponse = searchResponses.get(i);
                setSearchVideoToShow(searchResponse);
                switchFragment(HomeActivity.FRAGMENT_VIDEO_SEARCH, false, "Video Details");
       }


         else if((searchResponses!=null)&&(!searchResponses.get(i).getIsVideo()))
       {
                mSingleClickHandle.put(ENABLE_FRAGMENT_SEARCH_VIEW, false);
                setUserIdToShow(searchResponses.get(i).getUserId2());
                closeDrawer();
                switchFragment(HomeActivity.FRAGMENT_PROFILE_VIEW, false, "video");
       }


        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your  web services separatly and locate those results in two different lists,
then copy those list values into searchResponses.

you can merge the results as follows  if their type is equal,

```
for(int i = 0; i < searchFeedList.size() ; i ++)
{
    searchResponses.add(searchFeedList.get(i);
}

int totalSoze = searchFeedList.size() + searchUserList.size();

for(int j = searchFeedList.size(); j < totalSoze.size() ; j ++)
{
    searchResponses.add(searchUserList.get(j);
}
```

Comment: okay..suppose i stored first api response in searchFeedList and second api response in searchUserList..then do i need to merge both the list in third list and how can i do that?

Comment: thanks..I have updated question according to ur answer.it never goes inside for loop..and crashes on clicking on list item..where am i going wrong?

Comment: updated question again..please check the updated question..still i am getting index out of bound exception sometimes as searchResponses  list size becoming zero..please tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: from first api call i am creating list searchresponse and from second api call creating list searchUserresponse and appendingdata to searchresponse list

Comment: can you debug and find which line give you the exception please ?

Comment: searchResponses.get(i).getIsVideo() inside onSuggestionClick() gives index out of bound exception sometimes as size of list is zero